# Oracle, grant select on any table except 1

Tags: sql, oracle, roles

I would like to make an user access all tables from my DB except for 1 table which will be 'MY_SECRET_TABLE' as example.
My solution is not working currently... :

```
Grant select any table to public;
Grant select any table to MY_USER;
Revoke all on MY_SECRET_TABLE from MY_USER;
```

But i can still access the table.
Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks,

Comment: with "still access the table", do you mean it still shows up in the list of tables, or you can actually SELECT from it?

Comment: yes, I can still "select * from MY_SECRET_TABLE"

Comment: Of course you can still select from MY_SECRET_TABLE, but can other users?

Comment: yes but it seems normal to me since I "grant select to any table to public". I want to deny access only to MY_USER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by obtaining the executable grants through a SQL

```
SELECT   'GRANT SELECT ON ' || object_name || ' TO USERNAME;'
FROM     user_objects
WHERE    object_type = 'TABLE' AND object_name != 'EXCEPT_THIS_TABLE'
ORDER BY object_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

GRANT SELECT ON ANY TABLE is a very powerful privilege, so you may want to rethink your strategy.

Anyhow the only solution I see is to use row level security so that anyone except MY_USER can select the table but no rows will be returned.

How does that sound?